# Drop down menu in main stackexchange site is not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

When I click on the drop down menu in [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com), it does not show the site browsing menu. Instead, it loads the homepage. But it is working fine on other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some initialization code for the dropdowns in the header got inadvertently deleted when the new footer got deployed.

This is now fixed and is in the processes of being deployed.

Thanks for reporting!